# How to manually create TAP output

Tags: perl, tap

There is a great Perl module
[Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::More) that everybody uses for
unit testing.  Here is the very simple script `t/sample_1.t`:

```perl
use Test::More tests => 1;

fail('This test fails');
```

I wanted to write script that does the same thing, but without
[Test::More](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::More).

I've read several the docs about TAP (test anything protocol) to find out how to write the script. I've read:

- [Wikipedia article about TAP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test_Anything_Protocol)
- [TAP specification](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Test-Harness-2.64/lib/Test/Harness/TAP.pod)

Unfortunately the documentation wasn't enough. I had to examine the output of script that uses Test::More to find out that I need to output diagnostics to STDERR (there was nothing about this in the docs).

So, I have written a script that does completely the same things as the script with Test::More script. Here is the listing of `t/sample_2.t`:

```perl
$| = 1;

print "1..1\n";
print "not ok 1 - This test fails\n";
print STDERR "#   Failed test 'This test fails'\n";
print STDERR "#   at t/sample_1.t line 3.\n";
print STDERR "# Looks like you failed 1 test of 1.\n";

exit 1;
```

But when using `prove` these 2 scripts output different things. The line "#   Failed test 'This test fails'" in `prove` is displayed on different lines for different tests. Here is the screenshot:

[image: Perl prove output for 2 sample unit tests]

I've written a test scripts that uses [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/module/Capture::Tiny) to check that STDERR, STDOUT and exit code for both scripts a identical. And the script shows that both scripts output the same things.

I've stored all the test files and a test script at [GitHub repo](https://github.com/bessarabov/manual_tap_generation).

My question. How should I write Perl unit test without Test::More to have the same output as with Test::More.

PS If you are interested why I need this. I need this to solve [the issue](https://github.com/bessarabov/Test-Whitespaces/issues/10) of my Perl module [Test::Whitespaces](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Whitespaces).

Comment: Why not fix your module to use Test::Builder properly? Then you can send diagnostic output (which appears with or without `prove -v`) using `diag`.

Comment: Thank you for the idea! I didn't know about Test::Builder. Test::Builder is in Perl core. I have created a sample script that does exactly what script `t/sample_1.t` does: https://github.com/bessarabov/manual_tap_generation/blob/master/t/sample_test_builder.t I will try to use it in my module. But I still don't understand why I can't create the output without any module.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I have found out what is going on.

[hobbs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/152948/hobbs) has [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17383186/how-to-manually-create-tap-output/17388568?noredirect=1#comment25235208_17383186) me to use Test::Builder. I created test script with
[Test::Builder](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Builder) that worked exaclty as the script with Test::More ([here
it is](https://github.com/bessarabov/manual_tap_generation/blob/master/t/sample_test_builder.t)).

Then I started examinig source code of [Test::Builder](https://metacpan.org/module/Test::Builder) to find out why the
source of such behaviour. Here is the part of lib/TB2/Formatter/TAP/Base.pm
file:

```perl
# Emit old style comment failure diagnostics
sub _comment_diagnostics {
    my($self, $result) = @_;

    ...

    # Start on a new line if we're being output by Test::Harness.
    # Makes it easier to read
    $self->$out_method("\n") if ($out_method eq 'err') and $ENV{HARNESS_ACTIVE};
    $self->$diag_method($msg);

    return;
}
```

So, this is the answer. `prove` sets up special environment variable
`HARNESS_ACTIVE` and Test::More and friends puts additional line break symbol
"\n" before any diagnostics that are printed to STDERR.

At last I've created test script that outputs exactly the same as the script
written with Test::More. [Source code of the script](https://github.com/bessarabov/manual_tap_generation/blob/master/t/sample_solved.t).

I really don't like this solution. It took me and outher peopler much time to
find out what is going on. I'm sure that the task of pretty output should be
solved in TAP parsers, and not in TAP producers.

=(

Comment: but TAP parsers job is to parse TAP, and the diagnostic stream (stderr) is not TAP.

Comment: Oh. This makes sense. I haven't realized that STDERR output is not part of TAP protocol. Hm. I think I's a pity that TAP protocol has no specification of how to output diagnostic data to the user. Because there is no such thing in the protocol the prove has to invent some hack that will make users life better.

Comment: TAP does cover [diagnostics](http://search.cpan.org/~petdance/Test-Harness-2.64/lib/Test/Harness/TAP.pod#Diagnostics) - any lines beginning with a hash symbol are treated as diagnostics.

Answer (score 2):

While I've got absolutely no frickin idea what's going on, I can get the outputs to match (visually at least) by including the following before any other output to STDERR:

```
print STDERR "\r";
```

This makes them match visually when run through `prove` or plain old `perl`. However, this is *NOT* what Test::More is doing.

The TAP you're outputting is per spec; if `prove` wants to treat it differently from the TAP Test::More is outputting, I'd argue that's a bug (or at least an oddity) in `prove`. Personally when I've written Test modules, I've always used Test::Builder or wrapped Test::More to output the TAP. Each of these is a core module. This seems to be what the majority of Test modules tend to do.

Comment: Than you! You were absolutely right. I should have written line break before any output to STDERR. It's strange but this is what Test::More is doing in case environment variable HARNESS_ACTIVE is true.